# How to create tag ( chip bar ) slider like Youtube in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, frontend

[image: Youtube chip bar slider screenshot]

Is there any package available to achieve something like this? I tried to look for libraries but couldn't find any. I guess I'm searching with the wrong terms.

I was thinking of creating a horizontal scrollable section and change scroll position based on the next, prev click.

But I would highly appreciate it if someone can suggest some available bindings or have a better solution. Don't really want to reinvent the wheel and deal with lot of problems.